# How can I get an attribute in a class from a superclass?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to use Hibernate. I have a database schema and I would like to write annotations in my code.

I have az A class. It's look like this:

In A.java:

```
public class A {
    public Integer id;
}
```

In B.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_b")
public class B extends A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    //How can I get that id attribute from the A class?

    @Column
    public String string;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with declaring it again in B?

Comment: I don't want to declare it again. I't would be good for me but my teacher/boss won't like id :) I would like to write in the correct way

Comment: Firstly you should learn [Hibernate Inheritance mapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html), and without those 3 strategies my preference is to define only relevant `getter & setter` in parent class.

Comment: Every attribute which I use now is public

Comment: add a getter in a and use that if it were private ... but since it is a public Integer just use it as id and you should have the value ...

Answer (score 0):

you put the annotation `@MappedSuperClass` above class A. The field id has to be annotated in clas A not B.

Comment: Ok, but it's not enough. How should I get that attribute from B?

Comment: you are inheriting it, so class B already has the field id. If you want to map the field id to a column you have to annotate it in the class A.

Comment: Ok. I understand. But I want to use that inheritance from a lot of other classes. For example C, D, E. And these classes is mapped for database tables too. How should I annotate that A class?